# Full Height Element Not Exceeding Parent's Height - CSS

Tags: css

I want to create a side navigation, which should be full height of the browser window. Each menu item (DT) has additional element (DD) where I will put some filters later on. When I click a menu item, its additional element opens, and pushes all other closed items to bottom of the menu. The problem is that once it's opened the size of the parent DL exceeds the screen instead of staying full height.

Could you please suggest a solution to resolve the issue.

HTML

```
<dl>
  <dt>Item</dt>
  <dd class="active">Filters</dd>
  <dt>Item</dt>
  <dd>Filters</dd>
</dl>
```

CSS

```
body, html{
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
dl{
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background: grey;
  height: 100% !important;
}
dt{
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
dd{
  display: none;
  margin: 10px;
}
dd.active{
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/jonsuthc/2/)

Comment: can you add the code that handles the click event?

Answer (score 0):

Please do remove `dd.active { height: 100% }` and check it...

Think this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The `!important` declaration is unnecessary. If you know the number of menu items (e.g. 2) and their height (e.g. 40px), maybe this could help:

```
dd.active {
  height: calc(100% - 80px);
}
```

An alternative (and equally inelegant) solution would be to use tables. Setting the table height to 100% will automatically stretch the rows with unspecified height to fill the remaining space (so only the rows that correspond to the menu items should have their height specified).

Comment: Good solution, but not suitable due to weak IE support. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
<dl>
  <dt>Item</dt>
  <dd class="active">Filters</dd>
  <dt>Item</dt>
  <dd>Filters</dd>
</dl>

body, html{
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
dl{
  display: table; /*changed*/
  margin: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background: grey;
  height: 100% !important;
}
dt{
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
dd{
  display: none;
  margin: 10px;
}
dd.active{
  display: table-row; /*changed*/
  height: 100%;
}
```

[UPDATED JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/jonsuthc/3/)